# I try to compare a split up string with multiple characters

Tags: javascript

```js
var input = 'HISFANTOR';
var output = [];
var char = input.split('');

for (var i = 0, len = char.length; i < len; i++) {
   if (char[i] == 'H' || 'K' || 'Y' || 'V' || 'B' || 'C' || 'N' || 'O' || 'F' || 'P' || 'S' || 'I' || 'U'){
      output.push(char[i]);
   }else{
      output.push('0');
   }
}
console.log(output);
```

I had it with cases first and it worked but looked way too much so I thought I try or but I get an output of the input

what I expect is this:

```
["H", "I", "S", "F", "0", "N", "0", "O", "0"]
```

Comment: You need `char[i] == ` in each of the checks.

Comment: A small tip for not using huge "or" blocks: just test if your character can be found in a target set of letters, using `if ("HKYVBCNOFPSIU".indexOf(char[i]) !== -1) { .. }`

Answer (score 7):

The pattern

```
char[i] == 'H' || 'K' || 'Y'
```

returns the first [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, which is the comparison with `'H'` or if the comparison is `false`, it takes `'K'`. All other strings are not used.

For taking a check if the character is in an array or a string, you could use `includes` ([`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)/[`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)) which checks a given value against an array or string and returns `true` or `false`.

This proposal uses [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) which takes a string, (basically any iterables, or an object with a length property) and returns an array of characters. An while this method contains a mapping functionality, you could check the character and return a differetn character, based on the check.

```js
var input = 'HISFANTOR',
    output = Array.from(input, c => 'HKYVBCNOFPSIU'.includes(c) ? c : 0);

console.log(...output);
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentionned in the comment you should add a check for every letter `char[i] === 'H' || char[i] === 'K'` ...etc.

Put the letters in an array, then use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert the string to an array, then use `[.map()][2]` to check if the letter exists in the letters array :

```js
var input = "HISFANTOR";
var letters = ["H", "K", "Y", "V", "B", "C", "N", "O", "F", "P", "S", "I", "U"];

var result = [...input].map(l => letters.includes(l) ? l : "0")

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

`char[i] == 'H' || 'K' || 'Y'` this won't check `char[i]` against each character,

you need to change it either

```
(char[i] == 'H') || (char[i] == 'K') || (char[i] ==  'Y')
```

Or you can use indexOf

```js
var input = 'HISFANTOR';
var output = [];
var char = input.split('');

for (var i = 0, len = char.length; i < len; i++){
 if ("HKYVBCNOFPSIU".indexOf(char[i]) !== -1){
          output.push(char[i]);
 } else {
   output.push('0');
 }
}
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, let me say that you have lot of answers that explains your issue and improve your code, so I'm not going deep on that. Instead, I'm going to show a different way to get your result using [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). The approach consist of replace all character not in some particular set of chars by `0` and finally `split` the resulting string to get an array of chars.

```js
var input = 'HISFANTOR';
var output = input.replace(/[^HKYVBCNOFPSIU]/g, "0").split("");

console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to  use`char[i] ==alphabet` with all alphabets. || does not work the way you used it

```js
var input = 'HISFANTOR';
var output = [];
var char = input.split('');

for (var i = 0, len = char.length; i < len; i++){
    if (char[i] == 'H' ||char[i] == 'K' || char[i] =='Y' || char[i] =='V' || char[i] =='B' ||char[i] == 'C' || char[i] =='N' || char[i] =='O' || char[i] =='F' || char[i] =='P' ||char[i] == 'S' ||char[i] == 'I' ||char[i] == 'U'){
            output.push(char[i]);
    }else{
            output.push('0');
    }
}
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var validChars = 'HKYVBCNOFPSIU'.split('');

var input = 'HISFANTOR';
var chars = input.split('');
var output = chars.map(c => validChars.includes(c) ? c : '0');

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex and Array.prototype.map

```js
var input = 'HISFANTOR';

out = [...input].map((char) => {
  return /H|K|Y|V|B|C|N|O|F|P|S|I|U/.test(char) ? char : 0;
});
console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex, it's an easy way to search all of this character in one short pattern.

```
var input = 'HISFANTOR';
var output = [];
var char = input.split('');

for (var i = 0, len = char.length; i < len; i++){
    if (char[i].match(/[HKYVBCNOFPSIU]/g)){
            output.push(char[i]);
    }else{
            output.push('0');
    }
}
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using forEach and indexOf.

```js
var input = 'HISFANTOR';
var output = [];
var char = input.split('');

char.forEach(el => {
  if('HKYVBCNOFPSIU'.indexOf(el) != -1){
    output.push(el)
  }else {
    output.push('0')
  }
})

console.log(output);
```